# machine representation of natural text

Tags: nlp

I'm currently working on high-level machine representation of natural text.
For example,
"I had one dog but I gave it to Danny who didn't have any"
would be

```
I.have.dog =1
I.have.dog -=1
Danny.have.dog = 0
Danny.have.dog +=1
```

something like this....

I'm trying to find resources, but can't really find matching topics..
Is there a valid subject name for this type of research? Any library of resources?
Natural logic sounds like something related but it's not really the same thing I'm working on. Please help me out!

Comment: Your representation is kind of funny, but without more detail about your goals and requirements, it is hard to criticize it.  As a pointer, perhaps you should look at predicate logic, like has(ref(I),dog), has(Danny,dog).  Resolving the personal pronoun (which I marked up as ref()) is tangential, but perhaps relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Representing natural language's meaning is the domain of **[computational semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_semantics)**. Within that area, lots of frameworks have been developed, though the basic one is still first-order logic.

Specifically, your problem seems to be that of recognizing **discourse semantics**, which deals with information change brought about by language use. This is pretty much an open area of research, so expect to find a lot of research papers and PhD positions, but little readily-usable software.

Answer (score 1):

As larsmans already said, this is pretty much a really open field of research, called computational semantics (a subfield of computational linguistics.)

There's one important thing that you'll need to understand before starting off in the comp-sem world: most people there use fancy high-level languages. By high-level I don't mean C, but more something like LISP, Prolog, or, as of late, Haskell. Computational semantics is very close to *logic*, which is why people researching the topic are more comfortable with functional and logical languages — they're closer to what they actually use all day long.

It will also be very useful for you to first look at some foundational course in predicate logic, since that's what the underlying literature usually takes for granted.
A good introduction to the connection between logic and language is [L.T.F. Gamut — Logic, Language, and Meaning, volume I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0226280853). This deals with the *linguistic* side of *semantics*, which won't help you *implement* anything, but it *will* help you *understand* the following literature. That said, there are at least some books that will explain predicate logic as they go, but if you ask me, any person really *interested* in the representation of language as a formal system should take a course in predicate and possibly intuitionist and intensional logic.

To give you a bit of a peek, your example is rather difficult to treat for
current comp-sem approaches. Not impossible, but already pretty high up the
scale of difficulty. What makes it difficult is the tense for one part (dealing
with tense and aspect will typically bring you into even semantics,) but also
that you'd have to define the **give** and **have** relations in a way that
works for this example. (An easier example to work with would be, say "I **had**
a dog, but I gave it to Danny who didn't have any." Can you see why?)

Let's translate "I have a dog."

```
∃x[dog(x) ∧ have(I,x)]
```

(There is an object x, such that x is a dog and the have-relation holds between
"I" and x.)

These sentences would then be evaluated against a *model*, where the "I"
constant might already be defined. By evaluating multiple sentences in sequence,
you could then alter that model so that it keeps track of a conversation.

Let's give you some suggestions to start you off.
The classic comp-sem system is
[SHRDLU](http://hci.stanford.edu/winograd/shrdlu/), which places geometric
figures of certain color in a virtual environment. You can play around with it, since there's a Windows-compatible demo online at that page I linked you to.

The best modern book on the topic is probably [Blackburn and Bos
(2005)](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/jbos/comsem/). It's written in Prolog, but
there are sources linked on the page to learn Prolog
([now](http://www.learnprolognow.org/)!)

[Van Eijck and Unger](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item5645253/?site_locale=en_GB) give a good course on computational semantics in Haskell, which is a bit more recent, but in my eyes not quite as educational in terms of raw computational semantics as Blackburn and Bos.